# Как передать данные с одного Activity в другое

Tags: java, android

Пробую передать данные из одного активити в другое. В результате выдает null.
не могу понять почему. переменные points, countTry, sec - инты.

```
 new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                            .setTitle("Congratulations!")
                            .setMessage("Do you want to save the result?")
                            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SaveScoreActivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("points", points);
                                    intent.putExtra("try", countTry);
                                    intent.putExtra("time", sec);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            })
```

В другом активити

```
  Intent intent = new Intent();
    String countTry = intent.getStringExtra("try");
    String points = intent.getStringExtra("points");
    String time = intent.getStringExtra("time");


    etPoints.setText(points + "");
    etTry.setText(countTry+ "");
    etTime.setText(time + "");
```

Comment: Разобрался. Тему можно закрыть

Comment: Если вы разобрались, напишите ответ - в будущем, это может помочь другим участникам форума.

Answer (score 1):

При получении данных, вы создаете новый пустой интент:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
```

И удивляетесь, почему в нем нет данных.
Доставать данные нужно из интента, при помощи которого была запущена Activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
```

Answer (score -1):

в putExtra() нужно передавать строковые значения

Comment: Напишите подробнее в чём была проблема и как вы её решили